# How do I create a custom redirect controller for Spring Boot 2 using OAuth2 client with different scopes?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-oauth2

My question is kinda unusual, I am struggling with creating a custom `@RestController` that initiates an OAuth2 login process for my application with different scope each time?

More specifically I have an example configuration like this:

```yaml
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          my-client:
            clientId: client1
            clientSecret: some-password
            // Basic the property `scope` is not provided here, but in the controller
        provider:
          my-client:
            authorizationUri: https://somehost.com/oauth
            userInfoUri: https://somehost.com/data
            tokenUri: https://somehost.com/oauth/token
            redirectUri: https://somehost.com/oauth
            authorizationGrantType: authorization_code
            clientAuthenticationMethod: client_secret_post
```

What I want to create is an API Endpoint that acts as a proxy endpoint to move the user to the login page based on the `scope` provided.

```java
@GetMapping(path="/redirect-to-login")
public ResponseEntity<?> proxyLogin(@RequestParam("scope") final String scope) {
 log.info("Received scope: {}", scope);
 // TODO: What needs to happen here, is that I need to generate a new login here
 // TODO: for the requested OAuth2 Client scope and redirect the user to the login page of
 // TODO: the provider with the scope.
}
```

I tried to receive all the client registrations for the `OAuth2ClientRegistrationRepository` and try to extend it to provide the scope there, but I was unable to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a registration for each "login profile" you need:

```yaml
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        provider:
          my-provider:
            authorizationUri: https://somehost.com/oauth
            userInfoUri: https://somehost.com/data
            tokenUri: https://somehost.com/oauth/token
            redirectUri: https://somehost.com/oauth
            authorizationGrantType: authorization_code
            clientAuthenticationMethod: client_secret_post
        registration:
          reagistration-a:
            provider: my-provider
            clientId: client1
            clientSecret: some-password
            scope:
            - openid
            - profile
            - email
            - offline_access
            - roles
          reagistration-b:
            provider: my-provider
            clientId: client1
            clientSecret: some-password
            scope:
            - openid
            - offline_access
            - whatever-scope
```

Then the frontend initiates the `authorization_code` flow by redirecting at the right URI: `/oauth2/authorization/{registration-id}` (sets a path value instead of the value of the request param you call scope)